# How does this drawing of a man's body in a pentagram suggest relationships to the golden ratio?

Tags: golden-ratio

[image: The drawing of a man's body in a pentagram suggests relationships to the golden ratio.]

According to Wikipedia it does, but I can't see how.

Wikipedia context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#/media/File:Pentagram_and_human_body_(Agrippa).jpg

Comment: Answered in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45774980#45774980

Comment: should this question be deleted?